# How to customize asp.net MVC validation message position

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

i am doing MVC model validation through data annotation and my validation message is showing just at right side of input but i want to show it at the below of input box like the screen shot.
[image]

so just tell me what i need to do without touching html. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alter `field-validation-error` and `validation-summary-errors` classes in CSS to make them reside on a new line. One way is to make them block elements by using `display:block` style. Here is a sample CSS:

```css
.field-validation-error {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: i really do not know how to force anything to appear on next line just by changing css....give me a idea. thanks